# How to filter SQL tuples by number of members

Tags: sql, tuples, having

So I'm working on an SQL problem, in which I have a bars and beer database from which I want to:
list all bars which serve a beer that Mike likes, and which are frequented by more than one drinker.

The database consists of:

```
likes (drinker, beer)
frequents(dinker, bar)
sells(bar, beer)
```

So I tried:

```
SELECT bar
FROM beer.sells
WHERE beer IN 
(SELECT beer
FROM beer.likes
WHERE drinker = 'Mike') AND bar IN
(SELECT bar FROM beer.frequents HAVING COUNT(drinker) > 1)
```

Which didn't work... why doesn't the count(drinker) comparison work as a filter to filter out bars that have less than 2 drinkers who frequent them?

Comment: Database, incl. specific version pls - some support features others don't.

Comment: _"which are frequented by more than **one** drinker."_ <>  `HAVING COUNT(drinker) > 2`

Comment: I believe frequents(dinker, bar) in table definition should be frequents(drinker, bar)

Comment: Is this your homework? studies?

Comment: Funny thing. I remember learning relational algebra with those very same relations (likes, frequents and sells)

Comment: Yeah, this is the practice database we get access to in my class... it's pretty funny that the bars and beers thing is pretty much universal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need a `GROUP BY bar` in the bar subquery. Otherwise, you'll effectively get `COUNT(*)` from `beer.frequents`, which isn't what you want:

```
SELECT bar
FROM beer.sells
WHERE beer IN 
(SELECT beer
FROM beer.likes
WHERE drinker = 'Mike') AND bar IN
(SELECT bar FROM beer.frequents GROUP BY bar HAVING COUNT(drinker) >= 2)
```

Comment: He was asked fro 1 but wrote 2, you should fix his error, see my answer.

Comment: @gdoron Yep, changed to `>= 2`

Answer (score 2):

You need to 'GROUP BY' for your aggregated COUNT to work:

```
SELECT bar
 FROM beer.sells
 WHERE beer IN 
  (SELECT beer
    FROM beer.likes
    WHERE drinker = 'Mike'
  )
 AND bar IN
  (SELECT bar
    FROM beer.frequents
    GROUP BY bar
    HAVING COUNT(drinker) > 1
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

*"which are frequented by more than **one** drinker."* <>  `HAVING COUNT(drinker) > 2` (**1**)

```
SELECT bar
FROM beer.sells
WHERE beer IN 
(SELECT beer
FROM beer.likes
WHERE drinker = 'Mike') 
AND bar IN
(SELECT bar 
 FROM beer.frequents 
 GROUP BY bar
 HAVING COUNT(drinker) > 1)
```